# When a non-subgaussian vector has subgaussian components

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, high-dimensional, inequality, subgaussianity

The following remark is from Asymptotically Normal and Efficient Estimation of Covariate-Adjusted Gaussian Graphical Model by [Chen et al. 2016](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256926721_Asymptotically_Normal_and_Efficient_Estimation_of_Covariate-Adjusted_Gaussian_Graphical_Model):

[image]

Here, $X$ is a design matrix with iid rows and $X^{(1)}$ the first row. The above implies that a vector $X^{(1)}$ with bounded entries such that $|X^{(1)}_j| < B$ is not necessarily subgaussian. Taken at face value, this is false: bounded random variables are subgaussian and a vector with subgaussian components is subgaussian.

I am wondering if the authors mean something else, for instance that $X^{(1)}_j$ can have unbounded subgaussian norm, which could happen if the entries are correlated. A large subgaussian norm could be useless for analysis in high-dimensional regression. Could someone clarify or point me toward some resources that discuss this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paragraph before the one you quote, they say "Let there be positive constants $M_1$ and $M_2$....".

I think that implies they are assuming $X_{ij}$ is bounded, but are not assuming $X_{(1)}$ is subgaussian **with constant parameter $M_1$**. That is, the boundedness assumption implies $X_{(1)}$ is subgaussian, but with a parameter that will in general grow with $q$.  The $\log q$ and $\sqrt{\log q}$ terms in the bounds come from applying Bernstein's inequality and I think would not be there with a fixed bound on the subgaussian parameter.  There's a comment in the proof of Lemma 1, in the paragraph after equation (36) to that effect:
*(all formulas involving $\varphi_1$ or $\varphi_2$ parameter of $X_k^{(1)}$ replace “$B$”
by “$\sqrt{M_1}$” under Condition 3′ hereafter).*

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! In the literature it seems to be that "non-subgaussian" could mean "subgaussian with parameter that scales with the dimension". I've encountered this in at least two other places.